# Grouping/summing arbitrary field

Tags: mysql

I've tried a few different solutions I've found with no luck.  The table I'm giving is an example that follows a similar design and function to the one I'm actually working with:

```
PK    |    Color    |  Count
----------------------------
1         Blue          4
2         Cyan          6 
3         Forest        3
4         Green         2
5         Indigo        5
6         Navy         12
7         Pink          8
8         Purple        7
9         Red           9
10        Violet        1
```

In this case, I want to break this up into color groups and list the sum.  For example, the group "Blues" would contain Blue, Cyan, Indigo, and Navy and would be a count of 27.  "Purples" would be 8 (Purple/Violet), "Greens" would be 5 (Forest/Green) and so on.

Given the information at hand, how would you do this?

Comment: I assume that you will manually define the groups?

Comment: Yeah. This applies in several areas where I'm working, so I'd have to manually define the groups for each different summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(case when color in ('Blue','Cyan','Indigo','Navy') then Count end) as Blues_count,
       sum(case when color in ('Purple','Violet') then Count end) as Purples_count,
       sum(case when color in ('Forest','Green') then Count end) as Greens_count
from your_table
```

Comment: Thank you. Tested and confirmed. Exactly what was needed.

In one application, I had to change `select sum` to `select count`, but the result was the same.  Thank you again.

Comment: I dount it is working with `count` instead of `sum`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e998b/2

Comment: In the cases where I had to go to `count`, it was necessary because it functioned as an internal code instead of a mathematical value.