# MySQL Combining specific fields

Tags: mysql

This is related to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164668/grouping-summing-arbitrary-field), but is different in formatting and execution (apparently).  I've tried using the information from there with no logical result.

Case example: The company has multiple departments.  We want to know where we're making our money.

Our table looks like this -

```
  Date  | Total | Item Description
-----------------------------------
12122012  1000      Butter cookies
12122012   600      Chocolate Coins
12122012  1500      Candy Canes
12142012  1300      Apple Pie
12142012  1300      Pumpkin Pie
12142012   900      Chocolate Cookies
```

I would like to retain the format exactly as it is, but group the products by candy, cookies, and pies.  Our code looks like this:

```
SELECT Payments_ReceivedDate AS date, CAST(sum(Payments_Amount) AS UNSIGNED ) as total, 
       tblTreats.Item_Description as 'Item Description'
       FROM tblPayments 
       INNER JOIN tblTreats ON tblPayments.Items_Ordered = tblTreats.Treats_PK 
       WHERE Payments_ReceivedDate BETWEEN '20120101' AND '20140101' 
       GROUP BY Items_Ordered
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- use a subquery
select sum(case when Item_Description in ('Candy Canes') then total end) as Candies_total,
       sum(case when Item_Description in ('Butter cookies', 'Butter cookies','Chocolate Cookies') then total end) as Cookies_total,
       sum(case when Item_Description in ('Apple Pie','Pumpkin Pie') then total end) as Pies_total
from (SELECT Payments_ReceivedDate AS date, CAST(sum(Payments_Amount) AS UNSIGNED ) as total, 
       tblTreats.Item_Description as Item_Description
       FROM tblPayments 
       INNER JOIN tblTreats ON tblPayments.Items_Ordered = tblTreats.Treats_PK 
       WHERE Payments_ReceivedDate BETWEEN '20120101' AND '20140101' 
       GROUP BY Items_Ordered) AS t
```

Comment: Thing is that this uses different tables than the other example.  It limits the use of "color" and "count"; replacing them with 'Item_Description' and 'Total'.  The issue is that by doing it with that information, it changes the table to output to lack a lot of information.  It winds up making `Candies_count`, `Cookies_count`, and `Pies_count` to be the total in just one field; it takes away the date.

Comment: My mistake, I'm going to edit the answer with the right columns.